# Apache with Worker MPM AND php-fpm

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, mpm-worker

I am willing to shift my application server from default prefork MPM module to worker MPM. My server configuration is

OS - CentOS 6
Apache - Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
PHP 5.4.35 (fpm-fcgi)
CPU - 4
RAM - 8 GB

I am only considering 60% RAM available i.e. 5GB. My apache process takes average 6 MB and php-fpm takes 25 MB.So based on RAM consumption I have following configurations

Worker Configuration:

Timeout 60
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

ServerLimit          16
        StartServers         4
        MaxClients           400
        MinSpareThreads      25
        MaxSpareThreads      75
        ThreadsPerChild      25
        MaxRequestsPerChild  0

PHP-FPM Configuration

pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
pm.max_requests = 500

emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 5s

When I add this machine to clusture the load average goes high upto 100 and behaves very strange.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated if I am doing any wrong configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but still. If you are really concerned about the effective memory consuming and performance, you should really consider moving to nginx + php-fpm, since you are already using the latter. Instead of switching to another apache process model.

Apache is memory-consuming and slow.
At least give nginx a chance.

Comment: How would you go about transitioning from Apache to nginx?

Comment: Easily. I'd write new config and just launched it.